# Method to find shortest road with Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: c#

I have to code a simulation and I need a method to find the shortest road from a position to another. This method only get an start position and a final position and return a list of positions who represent the shortest road between the positions.
Something like this:

```
public List<Tuple<int, int> ShortestRoad(Tuple<int,int> start, Tuple<int,int> end, int[,] park)
{//Code}
```

How can I do a Dijkstra algorithm implementation for this method?

Comment: your question is extremely vague, please be more specific. what road data do you have? what have you tried? code? have you looked into the a* algorithm?

Comment: I have an bi dimensional integer array. Is a class property so the method can use it. I'm just beginning to code... heuristics is too advanced for me!!

Comment: Not clear what you are asking than - BFS is a solution. There are ways to make search faster (like A* mentioned in the answer), but it looks like you want something else. Are you looking for something even simpler that brute force BFS?

Comment: I'm looking for a method to do it. I don't know how even BFS works!!! I'm looking for an implemented method to do it...

Answer (score 7):

You should look up the [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm), which is a **breadth first search algorithm with heuristics** to make it faster.

Essentially what the A* algorithm is a **breadth first search** like Dijkstra's Algorithm, but it uses **heuristics**, or **guesses about what the shortest path is** (a hint, you could say, telling the A* algorithm which nodes are better to look at). The use of heuristics can make the A* algorithm far faster than Dijkstra's Algorithm, because often it does not look at nearly so many nodes as Dijkstra's Algorithm does.

However, one thing to watch out for is that your heuristic function (a guess of the cost/distance between two nodes) *must never* be less than the *actual cost between the given nodes*. If your heuristic function produces a smaller result, than the A* algorithm is not necessarily going to find the best/shortest/least costly path.

Now, if you want some nice animations (especially regarding the differences between A* and Dijkstra's algorithm), then search both up on Wikipedia, where there will be an animation of the respective algorithm, performed in the same environment between both animations. It is easy to tell, from them, that the A* algorithm is better.

Comment: I'm just beginning to code... heuristics is too advanced for me!!

Comment: @abea Well, I'll describe what that means, but, really, just look the algorithm up. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm